# how to remove the underscore character inside the repeater in asp.net c#

Tags: css, asp.net, repeater

here is the [page](http://www.avakian.gr/Default3.aspx?categorysID=111&parentCategoryID=1&products=a) that has the problem, look at the photos with different views of the product, they are separated with an underscore character

i tried to use template seperator, and added a space character but that didn't do the trick.
Thanks

Comment: Could you show us the code in the repeater?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the underscore is because there is a space inserted somewhere and since the space is in the `<a>` tag, it makes the underscore.

Comment: thank you all for your answers. I had typed a space character somewhere between the a tag. now it is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is only happening in IE.  It looks fine in FireFox.  I would remove the  tags you have between the anchor  tags.  Instead, use the onclick event of the  anchor to call a javascript function defined on the page elsewhere.

```
 <a onclick="changeImgSize(this);"  href='http://www.avakian.gr:80/Images/products/basket2_04.jpg' rel='lightbox[Καρποί_και_φρούτα_]' id='Καρποί_και_φρούτα_]' style="width:85px;height:129px;" 
                                      title='Καρποί και φρούτα '>
```